# Update Angular model with custom event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a text input bound to a model value, and I want user input to update the model after a delay, but programmatic changes to the input value to update the model instantly, by responding to a custom event.

Here's what I put together based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31181416/165673)

**HTML:**

```
<input id="test_input" 
ng-model="test_value"
ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default customEvent', debounce: {default: 1000, customEvent: 0}}"
bind-event
>
```

**JS:**

```
myApp.directive('bindEvent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {

      $element.on('customEvent', function() {
        console.log('custom event is triggered');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.test_value = 'abc'; // starting value
```

But I can't get the custom event to trigger a model update:

**Console:**

```
angular.element('#test_input').val('xyz');
angular.element('#test_input').triggerHandler('customEvent');
-> 'custom event is triggered'
angular.element('#test_input').scope().test_value;
-> 'abc'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have done something like this before with `updateOn` custom events, and you should be able to trigger the `ng-model` update using

```
angular.element('#test_input').trigger('customEvent');
```

OR

```
angular.element('#test_input').get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event('customEvent'));
```

Here is an example showing this working: https://plnkr.co/edit/pxBFBPwbwjVJIBPhlis5?p=info.

I removed the `default` event from `updateOn` to show that only this event is causing the model update.

Disclaimer:
This example is just a proof of concept, but this type of hardcoded element selecting and event triggering does not belong in your view controller, but probably instead in a reusable directive.

Comment: Thanks, your example does work. The reason mine didn't ended up being a different issue (see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37801626/165673))

Comment: @Yarin oh yeah, i din't notice that you were doing it programmatically

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being that I was assigning the value programmatically, and I was able to remedy that by triggering an 'input' event before the 'customEvent':

```
angular.element('#test_input').val('xyz');
angular.element('#test_input').trigger('input');
angular.element('#test_input').trigger('customEvent');
-> 'custom event is triggered'
angular.element('#test_input').scope().test_value;
-> 'xyz'
```

Not sure why that was necessary, but it works...